# Spring Security REST Api for non-authorized connections

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, restful-authentication

I have an application and API. I am using Spring and Spring security for both. Authentication is required to access API.

I configured RESTFUL web service only respond when authentication is successful (handling with `JSESSIONID` after login) which makes querying database not possible if user is not logged in or credentials are wrong. But somehow, I need to access database and make some changes for forgotten password. I need to check if requested email is on the record. Also, update the database after password change. eg; If I make '`UPDATE USER`' action `permitAll()`, there will be a security problem.

Can you give me some ideas to handle that problem?

Comment: You can create some user with permissions to change password and later when changing password automaticly login this user -> send request ->logout user and all of that behind user view.

Comment: Yes, that is how I fixed this. I created a dummy credentials for this kind of non-authorized programmatic calls. Thanks !

Comment: You welcome. If you could set it to resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create some user with permissions to change password and later when changing password automaticly login this user -> send request ->logout user and all of that behind user view.